# Difference between convert -sample and convert -geometry

Tags: 11.04, convert, mogrify

I was making a small guide for facebook users on `mogrify` and `convert` ImageMagik subcommands, but I found that `convert` has `-sample` and `-geometry` options that for me look 99% the same.

What is the difference between the two? And if by chance, how do they differ from the `mogrify` version of `-resize`, `-resample`, `-sample`, `-scale`?

Just to make sure when to use them and why (in case of specific formats, sizes, colors, etc..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an explanation of the different resize options in ImageMagick on there website: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#other

Comment: Wow I was sure I checked that place out already. Did not find that at all. Thanks.